# use a static method from a sub class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, namespaces, static-methods

I have a super class called `API` in a separate file called API.js

```
class API {
???
}
```

I also have a bunch of subclasses each in a separate file (`MySubClassXXX.js`) that include a number of static methods like:

```
class MySubClass1  {
     static method1 () {
        return { something }
     }
     static method2 () {
        return { something else }
     }
}
```

I would like yo use these methods in my project like this `API.MySubClass1.method1()`

how should I import and define the subclasses `MySubClass1` in the main class `API`

Comment: Do these *only* include static methods?

Comment: yes they do. only static

Comment: Then you should not be using `class`es in the first place. Use object literals. Or instances of a base class if you want to share some of the methods and overwrite others.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a subclass definition to a property of the base class.  `class` declarations in Javascript are first-class values.

```js
class API {}

API.MySubClass1 = class {
  static method1() {
    return 'something'
  }
}

console.log(API.MySubClass1.method1())
```

If you only intend to use classes as namespaces here, you can also safely drop `class` and `static` keywords with the same effect.